# roc auc for small class imbalance

Tags: machine-learning, python, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes, roc

I have a classification problem with class imbalance(1:6). I'd like to know if roc_auc is a valid metric for this level of imbalance. I know it's not good for severe imbalance, but what about a case like mine?

Comment: Valid metric to do what?

Comment: to evaluate the model

Comment: My understanding of imbalance was like 1000:1 or 10000:1. I 6:1 was considered imbalanced, it would only be able to be used for a very very small number of classification problems. It would be basically useless for 90% of real-life data sets.